# get base (pool) of phone numbers (Perl)

Tags: perl

I have many numbers in DB. For example,

```
448-48-00 #(from 00 to 99, 100 numbers)
336-87-00 #(same as above)
449-20-00 #(from 000 to 999, 1000 numbers)
```

I need to get base of these numbers. For this example, I need to get 44848, 33687 and 4492.

I have this code, but I don't know, how to finish it :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use warnings;

my @p = 4484900..4484999;
push @p, $_ for 3368700..3368799;

my $data;

do {
    my $z = 1;
    while($z++ <= length $_) {
        $data->{substr $_, 0, $z}++;
    }
} for @p;

foreach my $key (sort { $data->{$a} <=> $data->{$b} } (keys %$data)) {
    say $key if $data->{$key} > 99;
}
```

I need to get the longest elements and remove short elements, which longest code contain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand what you're doing in your code and to improve it to do what you want. Disclaimer: it's not that simple, for example there's no way for an algorithm to see that you don't want to group `44848..` and `4492...` to `44.....` but that you want to group `4492...` instead of `44924..` and so on. But maybe this could already help you.

I think the important part is the "smart filter" which for example looks at `336` and `3368` and deletes the count of `336` if it isn't higher than the other (`336` marks a trivial super set of `3368`). Important here is the string-sort together with the `state` variable `$last`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say state);
use List::Util 'shuffle';

# shuffled phone numbers (don't make it too easy)
my @numbers = shuffle (
    4484800 .. 4484899,
    3368700 .. 3368799,
    4492000 .. 4492999
);

my %count = ();

# import phone numbers
foreach my $number (@numbers) {

    # work on all substrings from the beginning
    for (my $pos = 1; $pos <= length $number; $pos++) {
        my $prefix = substr $number, 0, $pos;
        $count{$prefix}++; # increase the number of equal prefixes
    }
}

# smart filter
foreach my $prefix (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %count) {
    state $last //= 'nothing';

    # delete trivial super sets
    if ($prefix =~ /^\Q$last/ and $count{$last} == $count{$prefix}) {
        delete $count{$last};
    }

    # delete trivial sets
    if ($count{$prefix} == 1) {
        delete $count{$prefix};
        next;
    }

    # remember the last prefix
    $last = $prefix;
}

# output
say "$_ ($count{$_})" for sort {
    $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} or $a cmp $b
} keys %count;
```

The output is absolutely right but not yet what you want:

```
44 (1100)
4492 (1000)
33687 (100)
44848 (100)
44920 (100)
44921 (100)
44922 (100)
44923 (100)
44924 (100)
44925 (100)
44926 (100)
44927 (100)
44928 (100)
44929 (100)
336870 (10)
(large list of 10-groups)
```

So if you want to get rid of the 10-groups, you could change

```
# delete trivial sets
if ($count{$prefix} == 1) {
    delete $count{$prefix};
    next;
}
```

to

```
# delete trivial sets
if ($count{$prefix} <= 10) {
    delete $count{$prefix};
    next;
}
```

Output:

```
44 (1100)
4492 (1000)
33687 (100)
44848 (100)
44920 (100)
44921 (100)
44922 (100)
44923 (100)
44924 (100)
44925 (100)
44926 (100)
44927 (100)
44928 (100)
44929 (100)
```

This looks very good. Now it's up to you what to do with the `4492`-100-groups and the `44`-1100-group. If you want to delete the 100-groups depending on their length, that could also delete the `4492` group in favor of the large `44` group.

Comment: Glad you like it. If you feel this answer was satisfactory, you should "accept" it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -l

use strict; use warnings;

my $prefix = "1234";

foreach (<DATA>) {
    print $prefix . $1 . $2 if m/^(\d{3})-(\d{1,2})/;
}

__DATA__
448-48-## (00-99)
336-87-## (-||-)
449-2#-## (0-9, 00-99)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
123444848
123433687
12344492
```

If you just want the higher value :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -l

my @arr;
my $prefix = "1234";
my $higher_prefix = 0;

foreach (<DATA>) {
    my $cur = $1 . $2 if m/^(\d{3})-(\d{1,2})/;
    $higher_prefix = $prefix . $cur if $cur > $higher_prefix;
}

print $higher_prefix;

__DATA__
448-48-## (00-99)
336-87-## (-||-)
449-2#-## (0-9, 00-99)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
123444848
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean range of numbers. Like 1234500..1234599, etc

Comment: You just want the biggest integer at the end, that's it ?

Comment: I mean, __DATA__ is real phone numbers, not masks

Comment: I have phone numbers and I need masks for all numbers. For 1234500...1234599 is 12345, for 3331100...3331199 is 33311

Comment: Your question seems too specific, I dunno what's a mask for you. Maybe it means a "prefix" ? Then it needs a simple concatenation... Post edited accordingly.

Comment: As I understood the OP (and his code) correctly he wants to *find* the prefixes from a given set of numbers.